# Different download options for the new Landsat ETM+ data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat-7

Can anyone give short info about the difference between:

- LandsatLook Natural Color Image (11.2 MB)
- LandsatLook Thermal Image (8.9 MB)
- LandsatLook Quality Image (2.5 MB)
- LandsatLook Images with Geographic Reference (22.5 MB)
- Level-1 GeoTIFF Data Product (270.4 MB)

I am trying to apply filters for feature detection in ArcMap on the Landsat data, but am I going to be able to make composite bands with the first four types of data? I guess they are simple jpeg images and won't give me any analysis value compared to the tiff data?

I don't want to download unnecessary files - the analysis process will produce enough chunk of data to fill a fully empty hard disk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ones labelled 'LandsatLook' are quicklooks with **heavily** degraded spatial, radiometric and spectral resolution and should only be used for quickly assessing image quality based on visual inspection.

As such, you should go for the **Level-1 GeoTIFF Data Product** for all applications where the results are of any importance, and not download any of the rest of the products.

Comment: I'd qualify that you ought to use the [atmospherically corrected products](landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-surface-reflectance-high-level-data-products) whenever possible, as the influence of the atmosphere is important. They also provide you with a nice cloud mask.